# 110 people divided into 3 groups of different sizes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computer-science

I need to distribute 110 people to 3 groups of different sizes as follows:
50 people to group 1
40 people to group 2
20 people to group 3

Instead of simply filling each group up to the desired size and then moving on to the next group, the distribution should happen in a "balanced" manner, so that

```
#1 -> group 1
#2 -> group 1
#3 -> group 1
#4 -> group 2
#5 -> group 2
#4 -> group 3
#5 -> group 1
#6 -> group 1
#7 -> group 1
#8 -> group 2
#9 -> group 2
#10-> group 3
...
```

This example will obviously not work, as group 1 grows too quickly in comparison to groups 2 and 3. Is there a simple division/formula that would achieve the 50/40/20 split?

P.S.: This is not my homework/assignment, but a "real-life" programming problem that I'm facing :)!

Comment: How do you determine whether a proposed distribution is "balanced" or not?

Comment: Good question. It doesn't have to be balanced in every state, I just don't want to resort to my above-mentioned "wait until there are 50 people in group 1, then start filling up group 2"-solution. The answer provided by Henry (evenly distributed every 11 turns) sounds good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to say that at each stage you should be as close to $\frac 5{11}:\frac 4{11}:\frac 2{11}$ as possible.  At the start you are exactly there.  Now adding the first person, your choices are $1:0:0, 0:1:0, 0:0:1$  Clearly the first is closest to the ideal, so person $1$ goes in group $1$.  Then person $2$ goes in group $2$.  For the third, you can have $\frac 23:\frac 13:0$ or $\frac 13:\frac13:\frac13$  Taking the absolute differences from the ideal, the second choice is closer, so number $3$ goes in group $3$.  Then clearly $4$ goes in group $1, 5$ goes in $2$, $6$ in $1$, and so on.  Because of the symmetry, once you are halfway through you can mirror image.  When you have a common divisor, as here, once you get the first tenth of the people you will just repeat.  So in your example, the groups are $1,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,3,2,1$

Comment: Thanks, Ross, I ended up using this method because it was easy to put the recurring sequence into an algorithm - works perfectly, thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you want as balanced.

A simple solution would be note that the highest common factor (greatest common divisor if you prefer) of $50$, $40$ and $20$ is $10$, and dividing by $10$ gives $5,4,2$.  So $5$ people to Group 1, then $4$ to Group 2 then $2$ to Group 3.  Then repeat.  Every multiple of $11$, you get the right balance.

If you are aiming for better balance fon non-multiples of $11$ then the pattern $1$, $2$, $3$, $1$, $2$, $1$, $2$, $1$, $3$, $2$, $1$, and then repeated as often as needed, will get you close.  This effectively applies the [Sainte-Laguë method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sainte-Lagu%C3%AB_method), dividing the frequency of occurance by odd integers and taking the highest quotients, to minimise chi-square divergence.

Comment: Eh, I should have thought of that, this very simple but just want I wanted, thank you! How would I express this as a formula (with the person's id as the only input, i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4...)?

Comment: Programming, you could take the frequencies of each group (say $n_i= 50, 40, \text{or } 20$), divide each group frequency by the odd numbers from $1$ to $2n_i-1$, and sort these quotients largest-to-smallest.  Then put person 1 in the group associated with the largest quotient, the person 2 in the group associated with the second largest quotient etc.